# Проблемы с selenium driver

Tags: python, selenium

Вот проблемный код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://yandex.ru")
driver.close()
```

И при выполнении получаю такую ошибку:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "categories_list.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

При работе использую **Windows**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо указать путь до драйвера

```
ff = "geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ff)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если внимательно прочитать ошибку то можно понять что `geckodriver` должен быть в пути. Так сделайте это, по ссылке ниже сказано как это делать.

> Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

[вот и добавьте его в PATH](https://www.google.com/search?q=geckodriver)

Comment: я скачал драйвер, что мне нужно делать дальше?

Comment: @evseygames в папку с скриптом закиньте

Comment: закинул, что делать дальше?

Comment: @evseygames мой ответ прочитай

Comment: @ПавелДурманов  теперь получаю следующею ошибку: selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities